# Date function on Field not working on a count

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, qlik-expression

I have a Count which is giving me the following error:

> Error in set modifier expression

The Expression is:

```
=Count({<date(STARTTIMEDATE)={"$(=Date(Today()))"}>} IDID)
```

`STARTTIMEDATE` is in the format of `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS:XXXXXX`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this by using  this in my load script:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST(STARTTIMEDATE as DATE),103) AS STARTDATE
```

Then this as my expression:

```
=Count({$<YEAR=,STARTDATE={"$(=Date(Today()-1))"}>} IDID)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to match the date format of the test string to the original.

`=Count({<STARTTIMEDATE={"$(=Date(Today(),'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS:XXXXXX'))"}>} IDID)`

In my mind I read STARTTIMEDATE as only a label / pointer for WHERE the set analysis should look rather than as a function to be evaluated

Comment: I have tried this and it now shows results, but it shows ALL results the same as if i did `=COUNT(IDID)`